# Update a column in a table having huge data (80mn+ rows) in cassandra

Tags: node.js, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

I have a table in Cassandra which has almost `80 million+` records(may be more than that). I have updated the schama which adds a new column in the table. Now I need to update the column values. I wrote a migration script to do that using `cassandra-driver`. Tried `batching`, `token` but the data is so huge that it is taking more than 3 hrs and still not updating the records (process getting terminated after 2-3 hrs.)
What is the best way to handle this type of migration ? Is there any other way to achieve this?

[Token example](https://github.com/nblair/code-examples/blob/master/datastax-java-driver-examples/src/main/java/examples/datastax/FullTableScan.java)

Answer (score 1):

Usually for such things it's easier to use Spark (although I'm not sure hot it works with Amazon Keyspaces). It's quite hard to do range scan correctly - you need to handle edge cases, etc. (I have [an example for Java driver](https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java) that uses the same algorithm as [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/) and [DSBulk](http://github.com/datastax/dsbulk/)).

You can use [Python with Spark](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md) and Cassandra Connector to update your data - the complexity of update will depend on your algorithm.

Another approach is put logic into your App - if it receives from Cassandra `null` for given column, you can return calculated value.